# XML parsing error mismatched tag Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command

Tags: ros

When I run roslaunch my_robot_description gazebo.launch I got error
... logging to /home/jainvrushab5/.ros/log/6adee896-bb82-11ed-ad22-af798fa7096b/roslaunch-jainvrushab5-Aspire-A515-57G-13014.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

XML parsing error: mismatched tag: line 129, column 8
when processing file: /home/jainvrushab5/v_ws/src/my_robot_description/urdf/my_robot.gazebo
included from: /home/jainvrushab5/v_ws/src/my_robot_description/urdf/my_robot.xacro

Check that:

- Your XML is well-formed
- You have the xacro xmlns declaration: xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro"
  RLException: Invalid  tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [['/opt/ros/noetic/lib/xacro/xacro', '/home/jainvrushab5/v_ws/src/my_robot_description/urdf/my_robot.xacro']] returned with code [2].

Param xml is 
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

my_robot.gazebo file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="my_robot" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" >

<xacro:property name="body_color" value="Gazebo/Silver" />

<gazebo>
  <plugin name="control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so"/>
</gazebo>
<gazebo reference="base_link">
  <material>${body_color}</material>
  <mu1>0.2</mu1>
  <mu2>0.2</mu2>
  <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
  <gravity>true</gravity>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="right_wheel_1">
  <material>${body_color}</material>
  <mu1>0.2</mu1>
  <mu2>0.2</mu2>
  <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="left_wheel_1">
  <material>${body_color}</material>
  <mu1>0.2</mu1>
  <mu2>0.2</mu2>
  <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="caster_1">
  <material>${body_color}</material>
  <mu1>0.2</mu1>
  <mu2>0.2</mu2>
  <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
</gazebo>

<gazebo reference="lidar_1">
  <material>${body_color}</material>
  <mu1>0.2</mu1>
  <mu2>0.2</mu2>
  <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
</gazebo>
<gazebo>
  <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">

    <!-- Plugin update rate in Hz -->
    <updateRate>10</updateRate>

    <!-- Name of left joint, defaults to `left_joint` -->
    <leftJoint>Revolute 2</leftJoint>

    <!-- Name of right joint, defaults to `right_joint` -->
    <rightJoint>Revolute 1</rightJoint>

    <!-- The distance from the center of one wheel to the other, in meters, defaults to 0.34 m -->
    <wheelSeparation>0.12</wheelSeparation>

    <!-- Diameter of the wheels, in meters, defaults to 0.15 m -->
    <wheelDiameter>0.100</wheelDiameter>

    <!-- Wheel acceleration, in rad/s^2, defaults to 0.0 rad/s^2 -->
    <wheelAcceleration>1.0</wheelAcceleration>

    <!-- Maximum torque which the wheels can produce, in Nm, defaults to 5 Nm -->
    <wheelTorque>20</wheelTorque>

    <!-- Topic to receive geometry_msgs/Twist message commands, defaults to `cmd_vel` -->
    <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>

    <!-- Topic to publish nav_msgs/Odometry messages, defaults to `odom` -->
    <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>

    <!-- Odometry frame, defaults to `odom` -->
    <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>

    <!-- Robot frame to calculate odometry from, defaults to `base_footprint` -->
    <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>

    <!-- Odometry source, 0 for ENCODER, 1 for WORLD, defaults to WORLD -->
    <odometrySource>1</odometrySource>

    <!-- Set to true to publish transforms for the wheel links, defaults to false -->
    <publishWheelTF>true</publishWheelTF>

    <!-- Set to true to publish transforms for the odometry, defaults to true -->
    <publishOdom>true</publishOdom>

    <!-- Set to true to publish sensor_msgs/JointState on /joint_states for the wheel joints, defaults to false -->
    <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>

    <!-- Set to true to swap right and left wheels, defaults to true -->
    <legacyMode>false</legacyMode>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
 <!-- hokuyo -->
  <gazebo reference="lidar_1">
     <sensor type="ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>false</visualize>
      <update_rate>20</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>720</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>-3.14</min_angle>
            <max_angle>3.14</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.5</min>
          <max>20</max>
          <resolution>0.01</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <!-- Noise parameters based on published spec for Hokuyo laser
               achieving "+-30mm" accuracy at range < 10m.  A mean of 0.0m and
               stddev of 0.01m will put 99.7% of samples within 0.03m of the true
               reading. -->
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.01</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
        <topicName>/rrbot/laser/scan</topicName>
        <frameName>lidar_1/frameName>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</robot>
```

..............................................................
*Help me to solve the problem ?*

Comment: According to the error message your error is in `my_robot.gazebo` but you haven't posted this file.

Comment: I have posted it gazebo file @riQQ please help ?

Comment: `/frameName>` is missing the `<` at the beginning, should be `</frameName>`.